# Dynamically create Silverlight Prism Shell?

Tags: silverlight, shell, prism

I would like to build a Silverlight Prism app with a configurable layout. Ideally, I would have a config file that specifies the location of all regions in my shell. The shell is then created at runtime from this config file.

Is this possible?

Can I have an "empty" shell and then programmatically inject regions into it at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution at the moment is to read a new shell from an XAML file at runtime and replace the old shell with it.

To make this even more dynamic, I can imagine generating the XAML file with the regions at runtime as well, before reading it.